# Tomcat Server when used amongst Selenium Grid setup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid

We are using a different style of Automation framework in our project (as per client request) wherein we have designed a JSP page and this page contains links and buttons through which each functionality of our application can be accessed (say on the JSP I select 'Purchase' it will open browser whichever is intended and runs a test to verify that functionality). We are using Tomcat server for deployment.

Now my question is if I introduce Selenium Grid setup into the mix (again as requested by client), is it sufficient that I run my Tomcat server on the Hub and I can access my JSP on all the nodes connected?

Answer (score 1):

Your jsp/tomcat server is basically another webpage/webapp.  As such, as long as it it accessible from all the nodes, there is no need to duplicate it.  This setup will mean you will need to put extra thought into your window switching as it will be used repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run the jsp page in all nodes because that jsp page is deployed to server so from any system you can access that jsp page.There is no connection with selenium grid here.Even your hub and tomcat server need not to be in same machine.